# When passing processed in the child result to parent, printf() outputs the proper value, but write() does not

Tags: c, io, posix, parent-child

It's a simple program that passes a value from parent to child which processes it and then returns it back to parent, which then is supposed to output the processed value to the terminal. While printf() does the job, write() doesn't output anything. If there is a way to output the result using write(), how should it be done?

```c
int main(){
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int id = fork();

    if (id == -1){ perror("fork error"); return -1; }
    else if (id == 0){ // child
        int x;
        read(fd[0], &x, sizeof(int));

        // ...
        // process x
        // ...
        
        int res = x;
        write(fd[1], &res, sizeof(int));

        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    else{ // parent
        int x = 10;
        write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));

        int res;
        read(fd[0], &res, sizeof(int));

        //printf() works whilst write() doesn't
        write(0, &res, sizeof(int));
        //printf("%d\n", res);

        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the issue is totally unrelated to processes and pipes. Your [mre] could be shortened to basically `int main(void) { int x = 12345; /* Or some other value */ write(STDOUT_FILENO, &x, sizeof x); }`

Comment: If you expect `write(0, &res, sizeof(int));` to print out readable values, like `1` and `978348957` depending on the value of `res`, then wouldn't be strange to use a fixed lenght like `sizeof(int)` (which is often  `4`) for how many bytes to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write` function doesn't know anything about text, all it will do are write the raw bytes.

So `write(0, &res, sizeof(int))` will write the raw binary data of `res`, which very likely will not be equal to any valid characters.

If you want to use `write`, use e.g. `snprintf` to "print" to a buffer, and then write that buffer:

```
char buffer[30];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%d", res);

write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

Comment: _which very likely will not be equal to any valid characters_ - For a single character is very likely to work in little endian, after all  is a byte set to 10 (a newline) followed by 3 bytes set to zero (NUL). For me it works printing a new line, it also works setting `int x = 'a';`